Postgres select including data from previous rows
Given a postgres table containing the following items:
tag_id,  duplicate_tag_id, tag_created_at_timestamp
14175,   14178,            ...
14175,   14177,            ...
14176,   null,             ...
14177,   14178,            ...
14178,   14179,            ...
14179,   null,             ...
14180,   null,             ...
14181,   null,             ...

Is it possible to write a query that will return tag_ids that don't have an entry in duplicate_tag_id column Unless that entry is corresponds to a tag_id that exists in the duplicate_tag_id in a previous row
So, in the case above, I would like the result to be:
14175
14176
14179
14180
14181

14179 is included because it was the duplicate_tag for 14178, which was already a duplicate_tag of 14175
Thanks!

Ah sorry - that date_stamp column is indeed a timestamp... not a date

So "previous" is decided based on "tag_created_at_timestamp"? Then the timestamps influence the result, and you should add its values. If "previous" is defined by the order on tag_id, the result could differ.

14178 is not included in your result, even though it was a duplicate_tag for 14177, which was already a duplicate_tag for 14175. Shouldn't it be included in the result, too? Or why is it excluded?

I am not sure if I understood completely the question, the following query return all tag_id if duplicate_tag_id is null (it does not exist) or if duplicate_tag_id equal to tag_id of the previous row .
Query
WITH previous_tag_id AS (
  SELECT tag_id,
       duplicate_tag_id,
       tag_created_at_timestamp,
       LAG(tag_id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY tag_created_at_timestamp ASC) previous_tag_id
  FROM myTable 
) SELECT DISTINCT tag_id
FROM previous_tag_id 
WHERE duplicate_tag_id IS NULL OR previous_tag_id = tag_id ; 

See example

Just select the tag_id's not duplicated but keeping the ones that are equal to its previous duplicate_tag_id, but not appear more than once in duplicate_tag_id, like:
select distinct tag_id from tags
where tag_id not in --duplicated
(   select duplicate_tag_id from tags 
    where duplicate_tag_id is not null)
or tag_id in --id = to prev duplicate_tag_id
(   select
    case when 
    tag_id=lag(duplicate_tag_id) 
    over (order by tag_id) then tag_id 
    end tg
    from tags) 
and tag_id not in --not more than once
(   select duplicate_tag_id 
    from tags t 
    group by duplicate_tag_id 
    having count(duplicate_tag_id)>1)
order by 1;

Result



tag_id




14175


14176


14179


14180


14181



Fiddle to test

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a tuple t1 whose tag_id does not appear as the duplicate_tag_id of a tuple t2, or appears as the duplicate_tag_id of exactly one t2 whose tag_id is the duplicate_tag_id of a third tuple t3. I assume that "previous" means that t3 preceeds t2, that is, t3.tag_id < t2.tag_id. This sounds like a three-way join of the table with itself, counting the tuples t2 and t3 (possible none, so left joins).
select    t1.tag_id 
from      tags t1
left join tags t2 on (t1.tag_id = t2.duplicate_tag_id)
left join tags t3 on (t2.tag_id = t3.duplicate_tag_id and t3.tag_id < t2.tag_id)
group by t1.tag_id
having count(distinct t2.tag_id) = 0 or count(distinct t2.tag_id) = 1 and bool_or(t3.tag_id is not null)

The result is:



tag_id




14175


14176


14179


14180


14181



View on DB Fiddle
